# windows phone 7 EventDispatcher Thread and UIThread

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a doubt about windows phone 7 EventDispatcher Thread and UIThread both are same thread or different. If both are different thread then how can i access the UIElement in the delegated Method or callback event method?

Please help me for finding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they're not the same thread.

If you're running on any thread other than the UIThread you can access the UI Thread via the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907%28v=vs.95%29).

To check if you're running on the UI you can use the [`CheckAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess%28v=vs.95%29) method.
To fire an action on the UI thread you can use [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29).

Comment: Thanks Matt for your quick reply, I know we cant access `UIElement` other than UIThread. and if we want we have to use Dispatcher's beginInvoke technique, but my question is "I have register for an mouse movement event in canvas" and on call back of event on mouse event i am accessing Textblock, Canvas without BeginInvoke and it wont throw any exception how? If both are different thread.

Comment: @Anieeh events in response to UI events are triggered on the UI thread. That is why you can access the UI from such handlers. Refering to the sender could be tricky otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use need to register an event in uithread and call                                             Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                { YourEventName(); }
                    );